# navigation-case of Jsf. Not working

Tags: java, jsf

Maybe I am making stupid mistake. But I cant find it.
Here is the code, everything is fine. Just can change to  the correct page./

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-action>#{user.isUserValid}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/loginSuccess.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-action>#{user.isUserValid}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>false</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/loginFail.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
```

xHtml Page

```
<body> 
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Username:" />
        <h:inputText value="#{user.username}" />
        <br></br>
        <h:outputLabel value="Password:" />
        <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}" />
        <br></br>
        <h:commandButton action="#{ user.isUserValid }" value="Login"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{user.loginState}" />
</body>
```

The path is correct. Dont know where is the problem

Comment: is the code going into your action ?

Comment: You need return Strings like SUCCESS or FAILURE for example in your Action Class.

Comment: public String isUserValid(){
  loginState = Boolean.toString(username.equals("user") && password.equals("user"));
  return "false";
 }

Comment: "false" is a string. And i try to change to fail. not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see from your code. isUserValid is returning a boolean value. Notice, from-outcome tag only accepts String value so boolean will not work.

[image]

source: google books

Comment: I cant not return a string lake true or false?